# I get Thread 1: signal SIGABRT and my IOS App crashes

Tags: swift, xcode

I am working on an IOS App on Swift and its connected to Firebase.  Once I reach a specific page in the run mode, my app crashes and I get this error message without any details.  Please help

I do not have any errors with my Outlets and I have tried debugging with break points but it still takes my to the AppDelegate with this error without details.  I am clueless.  Before it used to work the code should be fine and data were being inputted to the DB but something happened since I have created the login page.

```
//  LoginViewController.swift
//  Together


import UIKit
import Firebase


class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var usernameTxt: UITextField!        
    @IBOutlet weak var passTxt: UITextField!        
    @IBAction func userLoginBtn(_ sender: Any) {

        var pass = passTxt.text

        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: usernameTxt.text!, password: passTxt.text!){
            (user, error) in
            if error == nil{
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginToHome", sender: self)}
            else{
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)

                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }            
        }            
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have the GoogleService-Info.plist file added in your project?

Comment: Yes I do have it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I GOT THIS ISSUE SORTED FINALLY and The mistake was very simple.  If anyone is facing the same issue and you are sure you don't have any issues with your outlets, go the to Identity inspector and check the Class of each ViewController.  Make sure not more than 1 ViewController is connected to the same Class, especially if the class had code for a specific function. This was the reason why my App crashes and takes me to the AppDelegate class.  The code of the last page I reach before the crash did not have errors, but the only cause was having it connected to a Class used by another ViewController.